# How can i insert multiple images, in html tag using Python html

Tags: python, html, path, pathlib

i want to write multiple html file that contains multiple images at once but in the outputs files shows the last image in the list of images only

```
path = pathlib.Path('./'+str(f))

images = ['1.png','2.png','3.png'....]
    
for image in images:

     with open(str(f)+".html","w") as file:
            
          file.write('''<div class="card"><img src="'''+image+'''" alt=" "/>''')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'r code should be:

```
with open(str(f)+".html","w") as file:
    for image in images:
          file.write('''<div class="card"><img src="'''+image+'''" alt=" "/>''')
```